# Multiple color pickers not working

Tags: html, css, forms, colors, picker

I've got three color pickers, yet I've changed the classes however the `2nd` and `3rd` picker only change the selection on the `1st`, I thought if it was `JavaScript` it would be easier to change the selection. As such to duplicate the script and change the `ID`s of each of the three pickers. However I took this from `codepen` and it was only one color picker yet when I add more and even change the classes it still only selects the `1st`.

Could someone please give me a hand here?

Here is my code:

```css
 
<style class="cp-pen-styles">* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.colorPicker {
  margin-top: 1em;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-table;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 40em;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 0.35em;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
.colorPicker label {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  display: table-cell;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  letter-spacing: -0.5em;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.35;
  width: 1%;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
}
.colorPicker label.red {
  background-color: #ff3e05;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #ff3e05;
}
.colorPicker label.orange {
  background-color: #ff8d05;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #ff8d05;
}
.colorPicker label.yellow {
  background-color: #ecca05;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #ecca05;
}
.colorPicker label.green {
  background-color: #40af04;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #40af04;
}
.colorPicker label.blue {
  background-color: #057fff;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #057fff;
}
.colorPicker label.indigo {
  background-color: #7500ca;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #7500ca;
}
.colorPicker label.violet {
  background-color: #cc6fcc;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #cc6fcc;
}
.colorPicker label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 0.25em 0 0 0.25em;
}
.colorPicker label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
}
.colorPicker label:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
.colorPicker input {
  display: none;
}
.colorPicker input:checked + label {
  width: 90%;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}

</style>
 
<style class="cp-pen-styles">
.colorPicker2 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-table;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 40em;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 0.35em;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
.colorPicker2 label {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  display: table-cell;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  letter-spacing: -0.5em;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.35;
  width: 1%;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
}
.colorPicker2 label.red2 {
  background-color: #ff3e05;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #ff3e05;
}
.colorPicker2 label.orange2 {
  background-color: #ff8d05;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #ff8d05;
}
.colorPicker2 label.yellow2 {
  background-color: #ecca05;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #ecca05;
}
.colorPicker2 label.green2 {
  background-color: #40af04;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #40af04;
}
.colorPicker2 label.blue2 {
  background-color: #057fff;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #057fff;
}
.colorPicker2 label.indigo2 {
  background-color: #7500ca;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #7500ca;
}
.colorPicker2 label.violet2 {
  background-color: #cc6fcc;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #cc6fcc;
}
.colorPicker2 label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 0.25em 0 0 0.25em;
}
.colorPicker2 label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
}
.colorPicker2 label:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
.colorPicker2 input {
  display: none;
}
.colorPicker2 input:checked + label {
  width: 90%;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="CustomStylesCont" style="overflow:scroll;position:relative;width:50%;height:30%;">
<h6>Navbar</h6>
<form id="upload" method="post"  class="form-horizontal"action="***" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <fieldset>
<div class="colorPicker" >
 
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color" value="rgba(255, 62, 5, 0.5)" id="hat-color-red" class="red"/>
  <label for="hat-color-red" class="red">red</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color" value="rgba(255, 141, 5, 0.5)" id="hat-color-orange" class="orange"/>
  <label for="hat-color-orange" class="orange">orange</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color" value="rgba(236, 202, 5, 0.5)" id="hat-color-yellow" class="yellow"/>
  <label for="hat-color-yellow" class="yellow">yellow</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color" value="rgba(64, 175, 4, 0.5)" id="hat-color-green" class="green"/>
  <label for="hat-color-green" class="green">green</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color" value="rgba(5, 127, 255, 0.5)" id="hat-color-blue" class="blue"/>
  <label for="hat-color-blue" class="blue">blue</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color" value="rgba(117, 0, 202, 0.5)" id="hat-color-indigo" class="indigo"/>
  <label for="hat-color-indigo" class="indigo">indigo</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color" value="rgba(204, 111, 204, 0.5)" id="hat-color-violet" class="violet"/>
  <label for="hat-color-violet" class="violet">violet</label>
</div>
<h6>Feed</h6>
<div class="colorPicker2" >
 
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color2" value="rgba(255, 62, 5, 0.5)" id="hat-color-red" class="red2"/>
  <label for="hat-color-red" class="red2">red</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color2" value="rgba(255, 141, 5, 0.5)" id="hat-color-orange" class="orange2"/>
  <label for="hat-color-orange" class="orange2">orange</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color2" value="rgba(236, 202, 5, 0.5)" id="hat-color-yellow" class="yellow2"/>
  <label for="hat-color-yellow" class="yellow2">yellow</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color2" value="rgba(64, 175, 4, 0.5)" id="hat-color-green" class="green2"/>
  <label for="hat-color-green" class="green2">green</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color2" value="rgba(5, 127, 255, 0.5)" id="hat-color-blue" class="blue2"/>
  <label for="hat-color-blue" class="blue2">blue</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color2" value="rgba(117, 0, 202, 0.5)" id="hat-color-indigo" class="indigo2"/>
  <label for="hat-color-indigo" class="indigo2">indigo</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color2" value="rgba(204, 111, 204, 0.5)" id="hat-color-violet" class="violet2"/>
  <label for="hat-color-violet" class="violet2">violet</label>
</div>
<h6>Feed Content</h6>
<div class="colorPicker" >
 
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color3" value="rgba(255, 62, 5, 0.5)" id="hat-color-red" class="red"/>
  <label for="hat-color-red" class="red">red</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color3" value="rgba(255, 141, 5, 0.5)" id="hat-color-orange" class="orange"/>
  <label for="hat-color-orange" class="orange">orange</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color3" value="rgba(236, 202, 5, 0.5)" id="hat-color-yellow" class="yellow"/>
  <label for="hat-color-yellow" class="yellow">yellow</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color3" value="rgba(64, 175, 4, 0.5)" id="hat-color-green" class="green"/>
  <label for="hat-color-green" class="green">green</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color3" value="rgba(5, 127, 255, 0.5)" id="hat-color-blue" class="blue"/>
  <label for="hat-color-blue" class="blue">blue</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color3" value="rgba(117, 0, 202, 0.5)" id="hat-color-indigo" class="indigo"/>
  <label for="hat-color-indigo" class="indigo">indigo</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hat-color3" value="rgba(204, 111, 204, 0.5)" id="hat-color-violet" class="violet"/>
  <label for="hat-color-violet" class="violet">violet</label>
</div>
          <input type="text" id="usr_id" name="usr_id" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= $_SESSION['user']['id'] ?>" />

</div>
```

Comment: You've got multiple  elements with the same id. This may not fix your issue but it's bad practise. ids should always be unique regardless.

Comment: Thank you Novocaine it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `label`s are wrong (the `for` attributes) - they must match the `id`s that they are targetting. So all of your `id`s must be unique, which is not the case as your second two pickers have the same `id`s as the first one. On each of those,  change the `label[for]` and `id`s to reflect their being unique elements. Even better if you can do this automatically in your PHP project with a loop!

The classes don't affect this - it's all in the native browser behaviour between `id`s and `label`s.

Comment: Like @Oliver B said. But it's better to use "Strongly typed IDs"